# Python how to if loop?

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering how to put my script in a loop. I've tried an IF in an IF statement and a while statement, both to no success. I've tried to place while statement above the enterbox but it will give a block error. I am very bad at programming so bear with me.

```
import easygui

var1 = range(1000, 1200)
var2 = range(1200, 1300)

input = easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1")
input = int(input)

if input >= -1:
    easygui.msgbox(msg="Bye", title="title0"
else:
    if input in var1:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
    elif input in var2:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
    else:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")
```

And the while statement:

```
 import easygui

var1 = range(1000, 1200)
var2 = range(1200, 1300)

input = easygui.enterbox(msg="Fill in your number", title="Input1")
input = int(input)

while input >= -1:
    if input in var1:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer A", title="title1")
    elif input in var2:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Answer B", title="title2")
    else:
        easygui.msgbox(msg="Nothing", title="Title3")
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Problem solved! Thanks guys!

Comment: What did you try in your while loop?

Comment: I've put the while just above the if statement. I've also tried an IF in an IF statement with 'IF input >= -1:' and the rest of the code in the else to no success.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, the actual code used. That way we know what you are doing wrong and correct you for the same.

Comment: Try putting the `while` above the `input = ...` line, otherwise `input` can not change within the loop and you get an infinite loop. Also, don't use `input` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin function.

Comment: Thx tobias, this is just for reference sake, the original code is a bit too long.

Comment: @tobias_k I would suggest the same, but define your variable with some dummy value before the loop, otherwise you'll get an error.